# How to insert a part of an image into the textbox?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I'm trying to display only part of an image in text box.
The image dimensions are 200x50 pixels and i want to display only part of the image lets say from (25px,25px)(x,y cordinates) with height 30px and width 50px.

The above co-ordinates are decided by a third value, hence it varies according to the text in the textbox.

i tried using background-position and background-image properties, but didnt worked in my case.

How can i do it? What properties or tags should i use to make it work?
please guide me...

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clip in css..

```
img
{
clip:rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to insert an <img> with clip property set, into a textbox.becuse i want the small image to display in a textbox.

Comment: Have a look at here..http://www.seifi.org/css/creating-thumbnails-using-the-css-clip-property.html

Comment: thanks for reply. the article link you gave me uses an <img> tag to display clipped image. But i want to display the clipped image inside the textbox. If there is a way i can put it in textbox please let me know